# FFMPEG: merge multiple audio files to one but audio parts should be on specific location

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to build one long audio file from multiple small audio files but these parts should start at a specific time.

This is a command that I am using: (base audio is 135s long)
ffmpeg -y  -i base.mp3 
-i first.wav 
-i second.wav 
-filter_complex 
"[1] adelay=90068|90068[a1];
[2] adelay=130168|130168[a2];
 [0] [a1] [a2] amix=3" output.mp3

The command is working as it should, output file is being created but the delay is not as specified. The first small file has delay of 87000 (3s earlier) and the second audio has delay of 126000 (4s earlier).

This is the ffmpeg output:
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers

 built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)

 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib

 libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103

 libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102

 libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100

 libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101

 libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100

 libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100

 libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101

 libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

 [mp3 @ 059b4400] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 227.

 Input #0, mp3, from 'base.mp3':

 Metadata:

 encoder         : Lavf57.25.100

 Duration: 00:02:21.04, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 31 kb/s

 Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s

 Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono

 Input #1, wav, from 'first.wav':

 Duration: 00:00:14.88, bitrate: 352 kb/s

 Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s

 Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #2.0 : mono

 Input #2, wav, from 'second.wav':

 Duration: 00:00:02.57, bitrate: 352 kb/s

 Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s

 Output #0, mp3, to 'output.mp3':

 Metadata:

 TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100

 Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp (default)

 Metadata:

  encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame

 Stream mapping:

 Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0

 Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> adelay

  Stream #2:0 (pcm_s16le) -> adelay

 amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)

 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

 size=     384kB time=00:01:38.11 bitrate=  32.0kbits/s speed= 196x

 [libmp3lame @ 059eef60] Trying to remove 576 samples, but the queue is empty

 size=     551kB time=00:02:21.03 bitrate=  32.0kbits/s speed= 191x

 video:0kB audio:551kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.040223%

Is there a way to fix this problem, maybe with some additional parameter or something?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your base.mp3 duration is shown as 141s, not 135s. Might your base file be corrupt? Test by replacing it with `-f lavfi -t 135 -i anullsrc`.

Comment: Thanks, that is part of the problems. Initial command for base.mp3 generation was `-f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=44100:cl=mono -t 141 -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame  "base.mp3"`and it was working but duration was wrong. If I execute command 
`-f lavfi -t 141 -i anullsrc base.mp3` base.mp3 file duration is 144 not 141.  Also, after final mixing (adding delay) output file is 134 (shorter than base - 144)

Comment: Save to `.m4a` and check. .mp3 is a raw container.

Comment: Mp3 file is the reason for this problem. If I set extension to .m4a it is working as it should. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Save in container like m4a, mp4, mkv rather than raw streams like mp3/ You can still add `-c:a libmp3lame` to set codec.